# Azure App Services - add custom domain name without recycle

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a multi-tenant web app running in Azure App Services. Occasionally, we need to bind a new custom domain. Unfortunately, this causes the app to recycle - as I'm guessing the web.config is altered.

Is there any way to do this without a recycle?

Comment: Would staging slots help in this case?

Comment: @BrendanGreen - I don't believe that you can assign custom domains to staging slots - at least not in a usable way.

Comment: I just checked the web portal, and it seems to imply that you can - drilling into a deployment slot shows the custom domains option in the menu, but I dare say that this affects the site in it's entirety.  Would a work around that used two instances of your app with traffic manager in between workable?  You could disable each endpoint in turn and apply the updates.  From an end user perspective it'd look seamless, but feels a little clunky.

Comment: Yes, you can add custom domains to staging slots, but it wouldn't transfer to the production slot. Also, I don't think you can add the same custom domain to another app service inside an app service plan - so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this will avoid recycle but might be worth giving it a try.

You could associate a traffic manager with your app and then do the domain assignment on the traffic manager.

Traffic manager will work even if you have a single endpoint and might give you the indirection you need.

[image]

Comment: Worth a try, although Traffic Manager can't yet handle naked domains - so it's not a great solution at this point.